# How to I start with a clean session whenever I nightwatch opens the Safari WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, safari, nightwatch.js

Whenever nightwatch runs the tests in safari, it does not always start with a clean session. How do I make sure it always starts with a clean session?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with Selenium that it can not start Safari with no cookies. For more details see [here](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/381)